# Dynamic HQL query using hql expressions rather than Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a partially dynamic HQL query without resorting to the Criteria API for various reasons. I wanted to know if there is an easy way to short circuit a where restriction using HQLs expressions. For example, here is the original query which works fine:

```
SELECT customer 
FROM Customer as customer 
INNER JOIN customer.profile as profile 
WHERE profile.status IN :statusCodes
AND   profile.orgId IN :orgIds
```

StatusCodes is a list of Strings and orgIds is a list of Integers. However, either one is optional and shouldn't restrict if null is passed instead of a collection. I've tried to accomplish this like so:

```
SELECT customer 
FROM Customer as customer 
INNER JOIN customer.profile as profile 
WHERE (:statusCodes IS NULL OR profile.status IN :statusCodes)
AND   (:orgIds IS NULL OR profile.orgId IN :orgIds)
```

This didn't work unfortunately, but is there any other approach that might work, either with using different expressions or passing in default values?

EDIT: Just to be clear I'm looking for a way to use a NamedQuery, not dynamically building the query in any way.

SOLUTION: I used the extra query parameters to accomplish it. I created two helper methods:

```
private void setRequiredParameter(TypedQuery<?> query, String name, Object value) {
    query.setParameter(name, value);
}

private void setOptionalParameter(TypedQuery<?> query, String name, Object value) {
    query.setParameter(name, value);
    query.setParameter(name + "Optional", value == null ? 1 : 0);
}
```

And the query like so:

```
SELECT customer 
        FROM Customer as customer 
        INNER JOIN  customer.profile as profile 
        WHERE (:statusCodesOptional = 1 OR profile.status IN :statusCodes)
        AND (:orgIdsOptional = 1 OR profile.orgId  IN :orgIds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must avoid dynamic queries, you can do so at the expense of two additional parameters:

```
SELECT customer 
  FROM Customer AS customer 
  JOIN customer.profile AS profile 
 WHERE (profile.status IN :statusCodes OR :statusCodeCount = 0)
   AND (profile.orgId IN :orgIds OR :orgIdCount = 0)
```

In your Java code you would then do something like:

```
session.getNamedQuery("your.query.name")
       .setParameterList("statusCodes", statusCodes)
       .setParameter("statusCodeCount", statusCodes.length)
       .setParameterList("orgIds", orgIds)
       .setParameter("orgIdCount", orgIds.length);
```

You'll need to ensure arrays are zero-length rather than `null` or supply additional if checks to handle `null` scenario.

All that said, HQL is really better suited for well-defined (e.g. static) queries. You can work around dynamic parameters, you won't be able to work around dynamic sorting.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was suspecting, although I am still hoping there is a way to use expressions to avoid the extra parameters.

Comment: @user842800 There isn't - not for lists. Hibernate's query processor has to do some magic behind the scenes to support lists (specifically, count the number of elements and generate the appropriate number of positional parameters in resulting SQL) so  passing in <code>null</code> is not an option.

Comment: What about SQL injection possibility?

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is to put all parameters in a map and build the query dynamic, after building before execution set all parameters required by the query taking values from the map:

```
Map<String, Object> pars = new HashMap<String,Object>();
pars.put("statusCodes", statusCodes);
pars.put("orgIds", orgIds);

StringBuilder b = "SELECT customer FROM Customer as customer INNER JOIN customer.profile as profile where 1 = 1";
if (statusCodes != null) {
  b.append(" and profile.status in :statusCodes");
}
if (orgIds != null) {
  b.append(" and profile.orgId in :statusCodes");
}

...

Query q = session.createQuery(b.toString());

...

for (String p : q.getNamedParameters()) {
  q.setParameter(p, pars.get(p));
}
```

Of course some improvements are needed for example throw exception when parameters is not set, use typed parameter if complexity is bigger than a few simple parameters and so on.

Comment: What about SQL injection probability?

Comment: There is no chance for sql injection in this case, it is handled as a parameter and as such it has its content escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to generate your query dynamically:

```
StringBuilder hql = 
    new StringBuilder("SELECT customer FROM Customer as customer INNER JOIN customer.profile as profile where 1 = 1")
if (statusCodes != null) {
    hql.append(" and profile.status IN :statusCodes");
}
if (orgIds != null) {
    hql.append(" and profile.orgId IN :orgIds");
}
```

Of course, you will also have to set the parameters to the query only if they're not null.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to avoid writing any dynamic queries. I want the queries to live in the .hbm files because some will inevitably need to be tweaked or converted to native queries. So there must be some way of maintaining them as named queries rather than dynamically constructing them.

Comment: Then, AFAIK, you'll need 4 different queries: one for each possible combination (null-null, notnull-null, null-notnull, notnull-notnull). You just have to hope that you won't need a third parameter. Note that I don't really see how changing the static HQL to SQL in an xml file is much easier than changing the dynamic HQL to dynamic SQL in the Java file.

Comment: The benefit comes from the fact that the app doesn't need to know if a named query is hql or sql. They can simply be swapped out in an xml file by a dba even. And I'm looking to use OR conditions to avoid having multiple queries.