# How to apply OR Condition in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an HQL query that takes `msisdn` and `subServiceId` on an Entity Unsubscription.

Below is the code for the same:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(unsubscriptionInfodemo)
                .addEntity(Unsubscription.class)
                .setParameter("msisdn", msisdn)
                .setParameter("subServiceId", subServiceId);
```

Now,I need to check in this `Unsubscription` entity whether `subServiceId` is the `subServiceId` I have passed or it should be the `subServiceId` I have hardCoded.

Can I apply like

```
public void checkUser(String msisdn,String subServiceID){
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(unsubscriptionInfodemo)
                .addEntity(Unsubscription.class)
                .setParameter("msisdn", msisdn)
                .setParameter("subServiceId", subServiceId)
                .setParameter("subServiceId", "XYZ");
}
```

HQL query:

```
unsubscriptionInfodemo=select * from unsubscription s where s.msisdn=:msisdn and s.subservice_id=:subServiceId
```

> Can anyone guide me how to proceed?

Comment: `unsubscriptionInfodemo` what is the value of this?

Comment: Yeah, without showing your query it is kind of pointless to ask.

Comment: Okay Edited the Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to apply OR Condition in HQL?

use `OR` on your query:

```
select * from unsubscription s where s.msisdn=:msisdn and s.subservice_id=:subServiceId OR 
s.subservice_id=:subServiceId2
```

and name parameters shouldn't be the same:

```
.setParameter("msisdn", msisdn)
.setParameter("subServiceId", subServiceId)
.setParameter("subServiceId2", "XYZ"); // Make this subServiceId2
```

Comment: Can I do like this select * from unsubscription s where s.msisdn=:msisdn and s.subservice_id IN (subServiceId,subServiceId2)
.setParameter("msisdn", msisdn)
.setParameter("subServiceId", subServiceId)
.setParameter("subServiceId2", "XYZ"); // Make this subServiceId2

Answer (score -1):

The dynamic functionality you want to implement cannot be done with hql without changing the hql string.

I would consider using the [criteria api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) which provides a dynamic functionality.

The easiest way is to either create the hql string based on the value (if subServiceId is existent or not) or use the criteria api, thus you will just have to add one extra equals filter in case of subServiceId presence.

The question should be changed on how to add dynamic conditions to hql based on variable presence.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640736/dynamic-hql-query-using-hql-expressions-rather-than-criteria)